# Ember.js: Internal hyperlinks when pulling from a database

Tags: ember.js

My database sometimes contains hyperlinks (regular HTML "a" tags) to other routes within my Ember.js application. The issue is that I do not know how to have it so those links will be transitioned within Ember instead of having to reload the page. Is there any way to get around this issue?

Example: I have a blog (/blog) post that a user creates. This blog post will have links to other sections of the site, such as contacts (/contact). How can I get the link in the blog post to transition through Ember rather than reloading the app each time a link is clicked?

EDIT: Have not found an easy way to fix this issue within Ember. I thought this would be a more common issue than it is. I did find a very rudimentary way around the problem using jQuery. I catch all "a" clicks within the content area and run it through a try/catch block. If it cannot transition through Ember then it will throw an error, which means we can just route using traditional Javascript. This is probably far from optimal, but is good enough for me for now.

```
Ember.$('.ember-linkify a').click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  a = $(this).attr 'href'
  try
    @transitionTo a
  catch error
    window.location.href = a
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store route names instead of storing HTML elements, because if I understand good you store:

```
<a href="/contact"></a>
```

instead of:

```
contact
```

So if you rewrite your logic to store only route names you could make Ember handle that.

If you would have variable which stores route name (`/contact` in your example) and it's member of `product` then you probably could access it like that:

```
product.link
```

You can pass this string to `{{link-to}}` helper and this would result in correct Ember link:

```
{{#link-to product.link}}Link{{/link-to}}
```

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/72a91b2c61379c7d4fe0)
- [Full code behind demo.](http://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/72a91b2c61379c7d4fe0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should have been more detailed. The links will be mixed in with other HTML content. The content will be editable by admin users using a WYSIYG editor (CKEditor). I would like to allow them to use normal HTML elements.The easiest way to think about it is a blog post. Users should be able to create content which will allow links to different sections of the website.

Comment: Okay, I get it. The solution would be to create parse logic for HTML anchor links and extract from HTML markup route names, styling, value of elements, then use `link-to` helper in Ember, but well, it's complicated.